# How to Covert Html to PDF in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jspdf

I have some HTML text, that I want to convert into PDF using some jquery plugin...

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML($("#sectionId").get(0), 15, 15, options, function () {
  pdf.save('@(Html.Raw("textdoc.pdf")'));
  return true;
});
```

Comment: https://micropyramid.com/blog/export-html-web-page-to-pdf-using-jspdf/

Answer (score 3):

you can use docraptor library to do so

```
<head>
  <script src="https://docraptor.com/docraptor-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    var downloadPDF = function() {
      DocRaptor.createAndDownloadDoc("YOUR_API_KEY_HERE", {
        test: true, // test documents are free, but watermarked
        type: "pdf",
        document_content: document.querySelector('html').innerHTML, // use this page's HTML
        // document_content: "<h1>Hello world!</h1>",               // or supply HTML directly
        // document_url: "http://example.com/your-page",            // or use a URL
        // javascript: true,                                        // enable JavaScript processing
        // prince_options: {
        //   media: "screen",                                       // use screen styles instead of print styles
        // }
      })
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    @media print {
      #pdf-button {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Example!</h1>
  <input id="pdf-button" type="button" value="Download PDF" onclick="downloadPDF()" />
</body>
```

**Here is the [link](https://docraptor.com/documentation/jquery) also**

Answer (score 0):

You could use tables of HTML to your side, it works with most of styles, such tool is called: mpdf. Atleast I was using it, and I didint have problems.

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf